# How to use the auto differentiation feature to compute the derivative of a vector with respect to a vector

Tags: tensorflow, auto, differentiation

I am using tensor-flow. The question is:

I have a vector x = (x_0, x_1) and a map:
y = [x_0+x_1, x_0-x_1].

I want to use tensor-flow's auto differentiation feature to compute the derivative of dy/dx. How can I accomplish it?

I search on the tensor-flow tutorial, it only gives me an example to compute the gradient of the following problem:

y = x_0^2 + x_1^2.

There is no example to show how to compute the derivative of a vector to a vector.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) of `tf.gradients` says:

```
tf.gradients(
    ys,
    xs,
    ...
)
ys: A Tensor or list of tensors to be differentiated.
xs: A Tensor or list of tensors to be used for differentiation.
```

Is something like below what you want to do:

```
x = tf.get_variable("x", 
                    [2, 5],
                    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))
x_0 = x[0]
x_1 = x[1]

y_0 = x_0 + x_1
y_1 = x_0 - 2*x_1

y = tf.concat([[y_0], [y_1]], axis=0)

grad = tf.gradients(ys=y, xs=[x_0, x_1], unconnected_gradients='zero')

with tf.Session() as s:
  s.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

  x0, x1, x, y, grad = s.run([x_0, x_1, x, y, grad])
  print 'x0=\n', x0, '\nx1=\n', x1
  print 'x=\n', x
  print 'y=\n', y
  print 'grad=\n', grad
```

Result:

```
x0=
[-0.02764007  0.01410516  0.02441488  0.02322472  0.03130293] 
x1=
[-0.00922771  0.0021055  -0.00121181  0.00638576  0.01953333]
x=
[[-0.02764007  0.01410516  0.02441488  0.02322472  0.03130293]
 [-0.00922771  0.0021055  -0.00121181  0.00638576  0.01953333]]
y=
[[-0.03686778  0.01621066  0.02320307  0.02961049  0.05083626]
 [-0.00918464  0.00989417  0.0268385   0.0104532  -0.00776374]]
grad=
  [array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.], dtype=float32), 
   array([-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.], dtype=float32)]
```